# VFS rename operation explaination

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel, inode, vfs

I am not sure the question is relevant to SO, maybe thread should be on unix stackexchange, but since this is code, I ask here.

In linux VFS, there is a struct:

```
struct inode_operations {
...
int (*rename) (struct inode *, struct dentry *,
        struct inode *, struct dentry *, unsigned int);
...
```

Lets rephrase the singature:

```
int (*rename) (struct old_inode *, struct old_dentry *,
        struct new_inode *, struct new_dentry *, unsigned int);
```

My test scenario is:
On source directory (inode=462251), I created file (inode=516564), Moved it to destination directory (inode=516511).

After investigated the objects I found that:

old_inode = source directory
old_dentry = file system object that I move
new_inode = destination directory
new_dentry = ?

If i inspect new_dentry->d_inode, it is null.
If i inspect old_dentry->d_inode, its inode number is of the file I copied.

I would expect that old_dentry->d_inode will be null after the move and new_dentry->d_inode will have value of the moved file.

What is the purpose of **new_dentry** object ?
If i print old_dentry->d_iname and new_dentry->d_iname - on both of them I received the name of the copied file, But why new_dentry->d_inode is empty ? shouldn't it contain the inode of the file I copied ?

Thanks

Comment: Parameter `new_dentry` refers to the dentry object, which will be created by `.rename()` operation. The same approach (passing a dentry which will be filled) is used for other inode operations, such as `.lookup`, `.create`. At the time when the operation is called, `new_dentry` object is not fully constructred. BTW, `rename` operation is usually one of the most complex for the filesystem's developer.

Comment: so new_dentry is the new filesystem object and new_inode is the directory it lies within (after rename)?

Comment: Yes, `new_inode` denotes a directory where new file should be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the purpose of new_dentry object ?
>   But why new_dentry->d_inode is empty ? shouldn't it contain the inode of the file I copied ?

new_dentry->inode will be valid if the destination already contains a file, which will be replaced if the rename succeeds. Something like `mv dir1/file1 dir2/file2` where file2 will be replaced with file1. In your case, there was no replacement; only renaming the file.